# Loop is skipping comparison incorrectly

Tags: arm, branch

The main problem is that the loop will only pull values from x[i] into z[i] and always skip putting y[i] into z[i]. The only thing I can think of is that y[i] always has a value larger than x[i], which doesn't make sense. Because x[i] is presenting the correct values to z[i] within the template.

```
    loop   CMP   r3, r4                   ; compare i and size
           BGE   done                     ; if i >= size, done
           CMP   r0, r1           ; compare x[i] and y[i]
           BGE   ygreat                   ; branch
           LDR   r2, [r0, r3, LSL #2]     ; R2 = x[i] or z[i] = x [i]
           B adding                       ; return to increment ygreat 
    ygreat:LDR   r2, [r1, r3, LSL #2]     ; R2 = y[i] or z[i] = y [i]
    adding:ADD   r3, r3, #1               ; i++
           B     loop
    done:  B     done
    
x      DCD    100, 3, -1, 2, 4, 4, 2, -1, 3, 100             ; r0 
y      DCD    -53, 247, 95, -7, 481, 91, -33, 1500, 29, -83  ; r1 
i      DCD  0                                                ; r3 
size   DCD    10                                             ; r4 z      
SPACE   40                                                   ; r2
           END
```

I have tried changing BLE instead of BGE, putting "B adding" below the branch to ygreat, moving the second comparison above the first, and many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

For each loop you need to do `LDR`, so you can make the comparison. If you have a debugger, you can observe `r0` and `r1`.  You will see that they are pointers and not the data.

A correct comment for the line,

```
 CMP   r0, r1           ; compare &x with &y pointers.
```

Here is a modification,

```
    loop   CMP   r3, r4                   ; compare i and size
           BGE   done                     ; if i >= size, done
           LDR   r5, [r0, r3, LSL #2]     ; R5 = x[i]
           LDR   r6, [r1, r3, LSL #2]     ; R6 = y[i]
           CMP   r5, r6                   ; compare x[i] and y[i]
           ADDGE r2, r2, R5
           ADDLT r2, r2, R6
           ADD   r3, r3, #1               ; i++
           B     loop
    done:  B     done
```

It is not clear what you wish to do with the largest (or smallest) value.  However, a key issue is that you are comparing the array pointer and not the array values in the loop.  I took it that you want to add the largest values of each array and store them in `R2`.  Conditional execution will actually work well for this case.  If you are on thumb2, you need to add an `ITE` instruction, but this looks like a text book example.

Comment: You can also use a count down for loops.  Ie, `subs r3,r3,#1` and then `bne loop`.  It does not require the 10 to be loaded in `r2`, which saves a register.